# How to merge Hash with Rails controller's params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Given a Hash with symbol keys, e.g.: `{ name: 'Jeff' }`, what would be the easiest method to merge it with controller's `params`?

Using the straightforward `merge` produces the wrong result:

```
> {a: 1}.merge(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(a: 2, b: 3))
  => {:a=>1, "a"=>2, "b"=>3}
```

The desired result is `{:a=>2, :b=>3}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways to merge a Hash with the params of rails:

1. Use `HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YOUR_HASH).merge(params)` or vice versa
2. Use `YOUR_HASH.with_indifferent_access.merge(params)` or vice versa

The order matters in both variants. The parameter of `merge(XXX)` overrides the settings of your Hash which called the `merge` method. If you want it vice versa, simply swap them.

FYI: Rails adds a new method to the Hash class: `with_indifferent_access` -> [Rails Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)